# Show all the table entries that belong to a specific entry in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a rails app and I have to models; Subs and Posts. Each post belongs to a sub, and a sub has many posts. In the Sub show view I want to list out all the titles of posts that it has.

Currently I have

```
<%= @sub.posts.each do |p|%>
  <%= p.title %>
<% end %>
```

But when I run that it shows:

> Test [#Post id:2,  title: "Test", created_at: "2015-07-29 01:49:58",
>   updated_at: "2015-07-29 01:49:58", user_id: 1, sub_id: 1>]

I want it to just show Test, instead all the whole table entry

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're using `<%=` in the line with the each statement, which means the result is outputted to the HTML, instead of `<%` which does not. The result of an `each` call is an enumerator object, which is the output you see after the title. The correct code would be:

```
<% @sub.posts.each do |p|%>
  <%= p.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it had to be something simple since I have been able to do it before.